# Interface key as value instead of type

Tags: typescript

A third-party library exposes different actions as part of an interface as given below:

```js
export interface actions {
   start: "start",
   stop: "stop"
}
```

After importing actions from this library, there's an equality check to be done as given below:

```js
import { actions } from 'my-library';

// as part of some logic where x is of string type but is essentially one of the actions
if (x === actions.start) { }
```

The above code throws the following error:

```js
'actions' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

How can we use `actions` interface like an enum?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a type at runtime, no matter where it comes from. So if this is coming from a dependency you don't control, then there isn't much you can do.

If the library does not export a value to use, then you aren't meant to use it as a value.

You are probably meant to do something like:

```
export interface actions {
   start: "start",
   stop: "stop"
}

const x: keyof actions = 'start'
if (x === 'start') console.log('start')
```

And you do get enum like behavior here because typescript will complain if you use something that isn't an action.

```
if (x === 'bad') console.log('bad')
// This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"start"' and '"bad"'
//   have no overlap.(2367)
```

Without knowing the specifics of that library, it's hard to give better advice.